# If I distribute amazon AMI with my service that calls LGPL software, do I have to provide source code?

Tags: lgpl

I have a question about licensing, and because my legal English isn't really strong, I was hoping for a simple answer...

My idea is to create a set of services, that uses command line programs which are licensed under LGPL and LGPLv3 and distribute amazon AMI for a fee. The question is should my code be also LGPL, and if not, can i charge people for this?

Comment: Cool! Just remember that none of us are lawyers either, and that the answers that we give are out of good faith, and are not legal advice :)

Comment: I thought some of you may have experience with this legal stuff.  :)

Comment: Oh no, I'm not saying that we can't give you an answer - I'm just saying that you can't use us as your lawyer. We'd still be more than happy to provide an answer though :)

Comment: Are you asking only about *using* free software to offer a network service? Or do you plan to offer your code to other people?

Comment: Amazon AMI is a snapshot of a OS. All the installed software is on it. On AMI would be my services and free software, but I intent to charge for it, if possible.

Comment: Oh! I misread "distribute an AMI with my service" as "use my service to distribute an AMI" `:P` I see now, of course, that you mean "distribute an AMI that has my service installed on it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is should my code be also LGPL, and if not, can I charge people for this?

The LGPL draws a distinction between two kinds of new work that make use of an LGPL-licensed library:

- modifications to the library, where the LGPL-licensed work is modified directly
- a "combined work" (or "work that uses the library" in v2.1), where a separate application *uses* the library

In the first case, changes to the library must be licensed under the LGPL. In the second case, only the library must be released under the LGPL; the application that uses the LGPL-licensed work does not need to be licensed under the LGPL. (It must follow a few guidelines, though. Notably, it must be easy to for users to make the application use a replacement library if a user wants to substitute the LGPL-licensed library with a different version.)

However, it's possible that you don't even need to follow any of these rules, if your code doesn't combine with the LGPL-licensed work into a single program in either of the above-mentioned ways. If your work is stand-alone program, and only invokes the LGPL-licensed work as a separate program, then your code not bound by any of the LGPL's rules. The distinction between one program with two parts and two separate programs that call one another is a hazy metaphysical and legal distinction; the [FSF has some guidelines on how they feel about the subject in their FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#NFUseGPLPlugins). If you wish to play it safe, then assume you do form a single program and license your work accordingly.

Finally, you may charge whatever you please for the act of transferring a copy of free software, even if your software is under the LGPL. See the FSF's article "[Selling Free Software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.en.html)" for a robust treatment of the subject.